# Closed linear span of compact open subsets of a spectral space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ac.commutative-algebra, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a [spectral space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_space) and $KO(X)$ be the set of all compact open subsets of $X$. Identify $KO(X)$ with $\{1_D:D\in KO(X)\}$, where $1_D(u) = 1$ if $u\in D$ and $1_D(u) = 0$ if $u\notin D$.

**Question:** Does the closure of $span {KO(X)}$ in $\ell^{\infty}(X)$ have a well-known equivalent description?

When $X$ is $T_1$, the closed linear span is $C(X)$, the space of all continuous functions on $X$.